# how i use plsql for sending csv file via FTP?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ftp

For the development of a solution of replication and consolidation between 2 schema oracle 10g distant. I want to use the FTP API (ftp.pks, ftp.pkb) to transfer a CSV file to an FTP server. when performing the dedicated procedure for that I have the error

> ORA-31024: Parser initialization failed with LPX-54 
>   error while parsing a stream to XOB

and I find no solution, can help me!

```
  PROCEDURE ftpTransfer IS
    vConn       UTL_TCP.connection;;
    vFileName   VARCHAR2(50);
    vToFile     VARCHAR2(200);
  BEGIN
    fileTransfer(vFileName);
    IF vFileName IS NULL THEN
        raise_application_error(-20002,'FTP - Erreur de Fichier');
    END IF;
    vToFile := RPLPKG_PARAMETERS.gServer.sDir||vFileName;        
    vConn := ftp.login(RPLPKG_PARAMETERS.gServer.sHost, RPLPKG_PARAMETERS.gServer.sHost, RPLPKG_PARAMETERS.gServer.sPort, RPLPKG_PARAMETERS.gServer.sPsw);
    ftp.ascii(p_conn => vConn);
    ftp.put(p_conn    => vConn,
          p_from_dir  => 'RPLDIRECTORY',
          p_from_file => 'HRM10122019.csv',
          p_to_file   => '/JOURNALS/HRM10122019.csv');
    ftp.logout(vConn);                    
  END ftpTransfer;
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35UUK.png)

Comment: There is no built-in FTP package.  So, presumably, you're using one of the third party packages.  Which one are you using (a link would be helpful)?  The documentation for that third-party package probably lists some prerequisites.  Are you sure you've met those?  Which line does the error get thrown on?

Comment: the link for this package : [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ftp-from-plsql) and the error are in ftp.login(...)

Comment: Which line in the login method is getting an error?  The `utl_tcp.open_connection` line?  Or something else?  Did you set up the appropriate ACL?

Comment: how I setup the ACL please ?

Comment: The article you linked to has instructions for setting up the ACL.  If you set up the ACL and you're still getting an issue, it would also be helpful to specify the version of Oracle you're using.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error in my question when executing the code for the ACL assignment.